# How to fetch supported series for a fragmentType in Cumulocity?

Tags: cumulocity

Continuing the question posted here: [How to get supported measurements of a device in Cumulocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830322/how-to-get-supported-measurements-of-a-device-in-cumulocity)

How am I able to fetch the possible measurement "units" (or series) for a fragmentType.  For example I have a device which supports the following measurement:

- Humidity sensor

For that sensor the following series are visible when fetching its measurements:

```
Humidity sensor: {
    Temperature: {
        unit: "Celcius",
        value: 26.28
    },
    Humidity: {
        unit: "RH%",
        value: 30.3
    }
}
```

How can I fetch the supported series for a particular fragmentType? For example in the case described above, I would like to get a list like this ["Temperature", "Humidity"]

Answer (score 1):

In the newest Cumulocity version you can fetch supported measurements. I was able to do it like this:

```
    function fetchSupportedSeries(childDeviceId) {
    var sensorsAndSeries = [];
    var query = "inventory/managedObjects/" + childDeviceId + "/supportedSeries";
    getDataThroughRest(query).success(storeSensor);
    return sensorsAndSeries;

    function storeSensor(response){
      for (var i in response.c8y_SupportedSeries){
        var sensor = {
          sensor: response.c8y_SupportedSeries[i].substring(0, response.c8y_SupportedSeries[i].indexOf('.')),
          series: response.c8y_SupportedSeries[i].substring(response.c8y_SupportedSeries[i].indexOf('.') + 1)
        };
      sensorsAndSeries.push(sensor);
      }
    }
}
```